# Using non-ext java script in Ext JS based project

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using Ext JS for my project. I got a sample javascript code from the web that I would like to try out. I couldn't find a right way to invoke the sample code form Ext JS based code that I have.

Is there an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "invoke". ExtJS is just javascript and you can call other javascript from it.

Here is a JQuery widget running inside an ExtJS container:

http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/08/extjs-jquery-together-same.html